# How can I create support organization?

Tags: security, permissions

How can I create support organization?  I would like to create a new organization so that the regular users can grant access to the user with delegated administration.

[image: New Support Organization]

Comment: With the above selection an Administrator can log in as any user. What else do you want to do? I dont think you need to anything else.

Comment: When the normal user wants to grant login access, they can only see Salesforce.com Support. If I give another profile user the delegated administration right, this profile user still cannot login as the normal user account.

Comment: A normal does not need to give login access for the System Administrator because of the setting seen in your screenshot above. As a system admin just go to the user detail page, and you should be able to see the Login button.

Comment: I edited my question. Actually I want to give the non-System Administration profile user with delegated administration to login as other user.

Comment: For Delegated Administration you need to go into Security Controls -> Delegated Administration,and create a Delegated group. The admin(s) assigned in the group will be able to login as the other users in the group. The users themselves do not need to do anything to grant access to the delegated admin.